# Determine remote IP for AppEngine Blob upload

Tags: google-app-engine, upload, client, ip-address, blobstore

Just a very quick question:
Is there a way to determine the remote IP of the client that uploaded a Blob to App Engine in the callback servlet that handles the request? The regular `[request].getRemoteAddr()` Java function returns the IP of the Google server that handled the upload and at least in dev-mode, the only extra header field I see is `X-AppEngine-BlobUpload = true`, which isn't helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no direct support. You could track this indirectly by stashing the IP address of the client you're generating the upload form to in the form. Then, once the blob is uploaded and control gets redirected to your app, it'll be available in the request for you to stash somewhere.

Comment: That would definitely be a solution. Thank you. Will be a bit of a hack in my case, though, since I'm actually uploading with an XHR request rather than a form...
Basically, I was looking for a non-obvious way to get an idea whether the upload is coming from the client that the uploadURL was intended for rather than someone who snatched or guessed the link. Do you have a thought on this?
Do you think I should file a feature request on this? Should probably be fairly trivial to include an "X-Forwarded-For" header or something to the callback request generated by the Blobstore service.

Comment: As the link is essentially random and only valid for 10 minutes after generating it I am not sure it's worth too much of your time trying to implement a check such as things.

Comment: True... Here's the "full" story: I am using a challenge/response authentication for every client request and I am storing the challenges in MemCache in a namespace derived from the client-IP to prevent a birthday-paradox-vulnerability in case the service ever becomes very popular. I guess I will just have a second set of challenges associated with pending uploads rather than a specific client-IP. It'll work, it's just not as clean as I would have liked...